# How to rename persistence volume claim?

Tags: kubernetes, persistence, rename, google-kubernetes-engine

**Is is possible to rename a PVC?** I can't seem to find an evidence it is possible.

---

I'm trying mitigate an "No space left of device" issue I just stumbled upon. Essentially my plan requires me to resize the volume, on which my service persists its data.

Unfortunately I'm still on Kubernetes 1.8.6 on GKE. It does not have the [`PersistentVolumeClaimResize`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/admission-controllers/#persistentvolumeclaimresize) admission plugin enabled:

- 1.9.1: [config-default.sh#L254@1.9.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.1/cluster/gce/config-default.sh#L300)
- 1.8.6: [config-default.sh#L254@1.8.6](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.8.6/cluster/gce/config-default.sh#L254)

Therefor I have to try and save the data manually. I made the following plan:

1. create a new, bigger volume PVC,
2. create a temp container with attached "victim" pvc and a new bigger pvc,
3. copy the data,
4. drop "victim" PVC,
5. **rename** new bigger pvc to take place of "victim".

The PVC in question is attached to StatefulSet, so the old and new names must match (as StatefulSet expects follows the volume naming convention).

But I don't understand how to rename persistent volume claims.

Comment: I just realized I messed up. I don't need to rename anything. After I copy the data, I'll then just drop & re-create victim.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer of your question is **NO**. There is no way to change any meta name in Kubernetes.

But, there is a way to fulfill your requirement.

You want to claim your new *bigger* PersistentVolume by old PersistentVolumeClaim.

Lets say, old PVC named `victim` and new PVC named `bigger`. You want to claim PV created for `bigger` by `victim` PVC. Because your application is already using `victim` PVC.

Follow these steps to do the hack.

**Step 1:** Delete your old PVC `victim`.

**Step 2:** Make PV of `bigger` Available.

```
$ kubectl get pvc bigger
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
bigger    Bound     pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6   10Gi       RWO            standard       30s
```

Edit PV `pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6` to set persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy to `Retain`. So that deleting PVC will not delete PV.

Now, delete PVC `bigger`.

```
$ kubectl delete pvc bigger

$ kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS     CLAIM            STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Released   default/bigger   standard                 3m
```

See the status, PV is Released.

Now, make this PV available to be claimed by another PVC, our `victim`.

Edit PV again to remove claimRef

```
$ kubectl edit pv pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6

$ kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Available             standard                 6m
```

Now the status of PV is Available.

**Step 3:** Claim `bigger` PV by `victim` PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: victim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeName: pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Use volumeName `pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6`

```
kubectl get pvc,pv
NAME         STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc/victim   Bound     pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6   10Gi       RWO            standard       9s

NAME                                          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    CLAIM            STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pv/pvc-8badc3c2-08c5-11e8-b07a-080027b3e1a6   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound     default/victim   standard                 9m
```

**Finally:** Set persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy to `Delete`

This is how, your PVC `victim` has had bigger PV.

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late response. I did not have chance to try out your solution yet, but just by looking at it it seems legit! I didn't know you could pull of a trick like that with `PV`. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Mir I followed these steps and I can confirm they worked perfectly.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use `--cascade=false` when deleting the PVC to prevent it from deleting the PV? I know this works when deleting a StatefulSet to not delete the Pods but not sure if it applies to PVCs also. That would make the process easier.

Comment: These two patch command examples can be used if using scripting vs. `kubectl edit`

Patch persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy:
`kubectl patch pv <name> -p "{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}"`

Patch to remove spec.claimRef
`kubectl patch pv <name> --type json -p '[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/claimRef"}]'`

Answer (score 6):

With Kubernetes 1.11+ you can perform on-demand resizing by simply modifying the PVC's storage request (https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/).

GKE supports this (I've used it several times my self) and it's pretty straightforward and without the drama.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot validate this however I am fairly certain that for GKE you can go to disks in the Google Cloud Console and find the one that the PV uses and resize it there.  Once you've done that you should be able to log into the node which its attached and run `resize2fs` on the device.  This is dirty, but fairly certain this has worked for me once in the past.

You don't have to unmount or copy to do this, which can save you if the disk is live or large.

Comment: Hi Derek! I can resize the disk, no issue with that. What I wanted to do is to resize persistent volume claim, but that feature is not available in my version of Kubernetes. To work around the issue I decided to go with data "copying" solution. It required that I rename one of the PVC. But that seems to be impossible...

Comment: Oh sorry I must have completely missed the `C` in all of that.  I know that resizing Persistent Volumes has been an annoyance for me as its not automated in some of these clouds.

Answer (score 0):

The answer *to* your question is actually **YES**.

Using the [rename-pvc](https://github.com/stackitcloud/rename-pvc) plugin of [Krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/setup/install/) installed with:

```
kubectl krew update
kubectl krew install rename-pvc
```

You should be able to rename yours like this:

```
kubectl rename-pvc old-name new-name
```

Note that you should create backups of your data in case something goes wrong. This [section](https://github.com/stackitcloud/rename-pvc#how-does-it-work) of the repo explains how it functions, by essentially updating the `claimRef` of the PV to the new PVC.